# How is a $Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$ proxy subclass implemented?

Tags: jakarta-ee, proxy, glassfish

In a Java EE 7 application, let's say I have a session bean class "`@Stateless public class MyEJB`". When debugging under Glassfish 4, I can see that a proxy subclass named `MyEJB$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$` was created (in order to provide Java EE container services to the EJB).

I am trying to figure out *how* these proxy subclasses are implemented. Is there a standard Java EE SPI which the proxy implementation calls, for example, to demarcate a transaction? Or is this done through container-specific internal APIs only?

(My motivation for this question is so that I could implement a portable CDI extension to enable true POJOs and OO programming in a Java EE context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy implementations are created by the `ProxyFactory` class. You can have a look at the source [in the Weld Github repo](https://github.com/weld/core/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/bean/proxy/ProxyFactory.java).

Basically proxy classes look like this:

```
public class Test_$$Proxy extends Test
{  
  public void doSomething(int someValue)  
  {  
    Testinstance = lookupBean();  
    instance.doSomething(someValue);  
  }  

  private Test lookupBean()  
  {  
    //get the correct instance from the BeanManager and return it  
  }  
}
```

Plus a lot of extra magic. Maybe you can get some details from [the CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/injectionelresolution.html) and from [this article](https://community.jboss.org/blogs/stuartdouglas/2010/10/12/weld-cdi-and-proxies).

Comment: Thanks! This may be just what I need; I will report back later once I have had time to go through the details.

Comment: The `ProxyFactory` class and others in the Weld github repo contain the answers, even if it's somewhat difficult to find the specifics. The injection of dependencies I already know how to do. The challenge now is to figure out which Weld methods to call in order to apply Session Bean services (transactions, etc).