# What is the meaning of '$' in toString() of a class?

Tags: tostring, ejb-3.1, stateful

I have a stateful Session bean named 'UserWS'. In the constructor of 'UserWS' I write toString() of the class.

```
public UserWS() {

        System.out.println("In constructor:" + this.toString());

    }
```

Some points are not clear to me:

1. At the first time I call a method of that class, the constructor called for  6 times. Why? I've expect it called just once. these are constructor calls:

> ```
> In constructor: ws.UserWS$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy@22c9b87b
> In constructor: ws.UserWS$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$@50933ff8
> In constructor: ws.UserWS@303709bb
> In constructor: ws.UserWS$$$view2@6872a8eb
> In constructor: ws.UserWS$$$view2@4e75aedd
> In constructor: ws.UserWS@53c4e19d
> ```

2. What is the meaning of '$' or '$Proxy' in result of `toString()` of a class?

Answer (score 1):

When a Java framework like EJB or CDI is used with a class you write, the framework has to generate extra classes, based on yours, that provide the services like Injection, Security or Transactions. Often these will be something like a Proxy that intercepts a method request from your client code, adds the extra service and then calls the method in your original class.

In your output you have 2 actual calls to the constructor of your `UserWS` class and the remainder are the generated classes which have constructors at least partially copied from your `UserWs` constructor. The '$' is just part of the convention Weld is using to name those classes.

You can find more details of how they are generated by Weld [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465410/how-is-a-proxy-weldenterpriseproxy-proxy-subclass-implemented)